# Force Parse Push Notifications to use PPNS instead of GCM

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ppns

For our Android app, we used Parse Push (1.10.1) to deliver notifications. But there seems to be a big problem in China (where GCM is not available) where only a small percentage of our users receive the notifications.

So for testing purposes, I tried to force Parse to use PPNS instead of GCM, but  I always end up with a "PPNS - Outdated Device" in the delivery report. The help says that the user might have uninstalled the app, but this is definitely not the case.

So far I've tried disabling the GcmBroadcastReceiver in the Manifest and also manually removed the GCM PushType from the Parse database (which should work according to the documentation).

Does anybody know why the devices get marked as "Outdated Device" when GCM is disabled and how I can force the system to use PPNS?